# Feature request for a panel that gives access to previous attachments

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently I have to search through my older replies to locate an uploaded image in order to reuse the same link in a new reply with relevant content. Reattaching the same image (at least when I can locate it in my  PC) would be an option but it is a waste of server space.

Would it be possible to add a panel where older attachments can be listed/accessed?
Ideally with an option to categorize the attachments in order to browse specific categories when searching.

Comment: Great idea. But I think something like this has to be suggested on the main Stackexchange meta, meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Passerby Should I make a new request there or ask a moderator to move this one?

Comment: I have posted a request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216650/feature-request-for-a-panel-that-gives-access-to-previously-uploaded-attachments